# Find out if a rectangle is inside another rectangle [C]

Tags: c, geometry

So I have two rectangles, the user has to input the bottom left point (x1,y1, but y1 is always 0) and the top right point (x2,y2),  and I have to find out if one of them is completely inside the other (or they are exactly the same).

And it'll be a bit harder since I'll actually have to make the program so the user can decide how many rectangles they want to create, but at first I'd be happy to know how to check in the case of 2 rectangles.

Comment: any code, you have tried?

Comment: Take a piece of paper and draw your rectangles on it. Does that give you a hint?

Comment: @Jongware That's actually what I did before asking this here, and no, it doesn't help at all. Let's say I have a rectangle where I know that one corner's coordinate is (1,0) the other one is (6,4), and the other rectangle has coordinates (3,0) and (5,2). I can see on my drawing that it's inside the other rectangle, but I have no idea how could I calculate/code it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Below is comparing the sides of the inner rectangle to the sides of the outer rectangle

```
if Right2 < Right1 && Left2 > Left1 && Top2 > Top1 && Bottom2 < Bottom1
```

Implementation:

```
struct RECT
{
    double x,y, w,h;

    RECT(double a,double b,double c,double d)
    {
    x=a; y=b; w=c; h=d;
    }
};


bool contains(RECT R1, RECT R2)
{
    if (   (R2.x+R2.w) < (R1.x+R1.w)
        && (R2.x) > (R1.x)
        && (R2.y) > (R1.y)
        && (R2.y+R2.h) < (R1.y+R1.h)
        )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should not it be like this? 
"if Right2 < Right1 && Left2 > Left1 && Top2 > Top1 && Bottom2 < Bottom1"

Answer (score 10):

Well, by definition one rectangle is inside of another if all the points of the inner rectangle are within the outer rectangle. Using a bit of geometry you can boil it down to checking whether the two opposite corners of the inner rectangle are in the outer rectangle.

Comment: I think you helped me figure it out, I'll check it soon, thanks.

Comment: Right, but not "by definition". The definition of "inside" is about all points of the shape, not about vertices. In the case of rectangles, it happens to be true because the container is convex, but that doesn't extend to non-convex containers. With a non-convex container, all vertices can be in the container and yet a part of the inner shape be out of it.

Answer (score 2):

Later is better than never, right?
I believe this is the short code:

```
private bool IsInside(Rectangle outer, Rectangle inner)
{
    return outer.Contains(inner)
        && outer.Contains(Point.Add(inner.Location, inner.Size));
}
```

Comment: What library are you using to define `Rectangle`?