# Algorithm Questions: how to determine rectangle is inside the another rectangle?

Tags: algorithm

Given a list of tuples (including x, y, width, height which four values define a rectangle in two-dimension coordination).
The goal is to check in the original list, whether one rectangle is inside another rectangle (if it is, only take the smaller one, larger one is discarded)

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious solution, if it isn't too slow, is to define `rect1.contains(rect2)` as:

```
rect1.x <= rect2.x && rect1.y <= rect2.y && rect1.x + rect1.width >= rect2.x + rect2.width && rect1.y + rect1.height >= rect2.y + rect2.height
```

and then check every rect in the list to see if it contains any others. (Don't check it against itself, though!)

Comment: Yes... *any* `rectangle` class, anywhere you find one, ought to be equipped with basic primitives such as overlap or containment. By all means, Hypnoz should *"find one* and just-use-it." ### When implementing your suggestion, the code must remember to ignore testing to see if a rectangle overlaps *itself!*  *(Been there, did that ...)*

Comment: I don't think that code is correct. If `rect2.x == rect1.x + rect1.width - 1` and `rect2.width == 2`, then your condition returns true, although rect2 is not contained (crosses the right border).

Comment: You need to make sure that `rect2.x + rect2.width <= rect1.x + rect1.width`. And similar for the y dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Check on this:

http://www.jstor.org/stable/2691523?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

and

[Find out if a rectangle is inside another rectangle [C]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768039/find-out-if-a-rectangle-is-inside-another-rectangle-c)