# Changing the animation and velocity in water

Tags: libgdx, collision-detection

I'm trying to make a 2D game in Java, and I'm using Libgdx. But, I don't know how to change the animation and velocity in water, for instance, changing the movement from walking to swimming.

Can anyone help me with the code and methods please?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use rectangular areas for your water and your sprites, you might want to look at [checking if a rectangle (your water) contains another rectangle (your sprite)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27768451/2586284). If you use non-rectangle shapes, you should find the appropriate methods to check if the hitbox of your sprite is inside your water.

If your water contains your sprite, you can handle (update, render, etc.) it differently.