# How do I find out if a rectangle can be covered by another rectangle?

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry

Given the lengths of the sides of two rectangles, I have to write code that checks if the first rectangle can be fully covered by the second rectangle. It's possible only to rotate the second rectangle to see if it can cover the first one.

A and B are the lengths of the sides of the first rectangle, the one we want to cover, and C and D are the lengths of the sides of the second rectangle, the one that will cover the first.

I have tried two codes and it still didn't work. The first is the naive solution, but I don't know if it's correct.

```
A, B, C, D = map(int, input().split())
if (C >= A and D >= B) or (C >= B and D >= A):
    print("covered")
```

Then I used my math skills to find out that the sides of the second rectangle (`l1` and `l2`) should `l1 >= A*sin(a) + B*cos(a)` and `l2 >= A*cos(a) + B*sin(a)`. `a` is an angle that can be `0` to `90º`. So my second code is:

```
A, B, C, D = map(int, input().split())

import math
a = 0

while a <= 90 and value == False:
    ai = math.radians(a)
    t1 = math.ceil(A*math.cos(ai) + B*math.sin(ai))
    t2 = math.ceil(A*math.sin(ai) + B*math.cos(ai))
    if (C >= t1 and D >= t2) :
        value = True
    a = a + 1
```

It worked for some tests I did, but my code didn't get an correct answer. So, what can I do to solve this problem? Are my ideas correct?

If I made any other mistake as grammatical, syntax or mathematical, feel free to correct me.

Comment: If you're dealing with a rectangle then isn't your angle a always equal to 90° ?

Comment: @vlemaistre No, arbitrarily rotated rectangles are still rectangles.

Comment: If only the side lengths are known, it wouldn't make sense to think about other inputs like rotation or translation.  Your “naïve” solution is rather trivially correct if you interpreted the input correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to check only three cases:

- when one set of sides is parallel to the first pair of sides of other rectangle
- rotated by 90 degrees to first case
- try to adjust one rectangle along diagonal of other

You don't need to check for any random angle. If it overlaps for any general case, it must do so in one of above three cases.

The third case will be a limiting case : consider a rod like rectangle in a square.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear in your code what are exactly the rectangle sides lengths.

But there should not be any calculation involving angles: `A` can be fully covered by `B` if, and only if, `A.length <= B.lenght and A.width <= B.width`.

(sorry I cannot comment)

Comment: Sorry for the misundestanding , I just edited my question. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Your first code part verifies if the second rectangle can initially fit into the first one, which is good. You can find other methods to do this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190410/find-if-one-rectangle-can-fit-inside-the-other)

> "It's possible only to rotate the second rectangle to see if it can cover the first one."

If this is a constraint, you can take a look to this [topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581058/rotating-rectangle-by-its-center) to rotate your second rectangle.

As developped [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768039/find-out-if-a-rectangle-is-inside-another-rectangle-c), I think a good way to iteratively verify if the second rectangle fits into the first one while rotating it is to check if *"the two opposite corners of the inner rectangle are in the outer rectangle."*

I know this is not a precise answer but I hope it will be helpful.